# CSS: Centering position: fixed

Tags: css, position, center, fixed

I came across a solution for (horizontally) centering a fixed position element as follows:

```
element {
    width: 200px;

    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

(where *element* is obviously the element to be centered).

The question is how does this actually work? Is this documented behaviour?

It’s a shame you can’t do the same thing vertically.

Thanks

Comment: just add a height and just `margin:auto` it will work fine `top:0` `bottom:0`

Answer (score 1):

You must set height to make it vertically center and `top` and `bottom` must be 0 also change the margin to this `margin:auto`

Try this one:

```
element {
    width: 200px;
    height:10px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: The problem with the above is that, at least on Firefox, the element is stretched from top to bottom (which can be useful) if no height is specified, or it stays at the top if the height is specified. `margin: auto` only works horizontally.

Comment: @Manngo try it first, take a look at this one https://jsfiddle.net/brt2ngz6/ it will center if you add a height.

Comment: @winresh24 No, you’re right. My own test failed because I was battling against other CSS for the `margin`. That’s two surprises: `margin: auto` normally doesn’t work vertically, and I still don’t see how setting opposite positions to 0 achieves the effect. Where is this documented? Once I find out, I can see which browsers support this behaviour. Thanks for the fiddle.

Comment: @Manngo As far as I know it's support all the browser. I can't remember where it was documented. You can accept the answer though if this one fixed your issue. Cheers

Comment: @Manngo - It's documented in [the CSS 2.x spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-height). In particular, see the equaity `'top' + 'margin-top' + 'border-top-width' + 'padding-top' + 'height' + 'padding-bottom' + 'border-bottom-width' + 'margin-bottom' + 'bottom' = height of containing block `. Note that this is describing absolute positioned elements. But [fixed positioning is a subcategory of absolute positioning](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#fixed-positioning)

Answer (score 0):

The element is centered horizontally because of this line (Margin:0 auto).

The 0 defines top and bottom margin. 
Auto = auto margin for left and right.  This is the key of making the element to stay center.

Vertically is different because the way other elements can be place on top and below the element.

You can use this page for reference -> https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Reference from Mozilla Developer Network -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/margin

Comment: Yes, but that normally doesn’t work if the `position` is `fixed`. My question relates to fixed elements.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I have an answer, thanks to [Smashing Magazine: Absolute Horizontal and Vertical Centering in CSS](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/). Here is the brief version:

- `position: fixed` or `position: absolute` removes the element from the normal flow, and the element gets its bearings from its container or the body.
- `top:0`, `bottom: 0`, `right: 0` and `left: 0` effectively stretch the element to its container. *For absolute & fixed position, they also define a bounding box.*.
- setting the `height` and `width` restricts the size of the box, so it isn’t stretched, *but:*
- The `margin` is calculated from the bounding box above. In particular, `margin: auto` causes the centering.

It appears that while a vertical `margin: auto` has no effect on normal elements (they are set to 0), they apply to fixed and absolute elements.

Note that the explanation above includes fixed positioning, which the article doesn’t focus on.

Thanks also to @winresh24 who pointed out the vertical centering. That help me to track down the solution.